# car battery unused for three years

Tags: battery, battery-charger

Car has been in the drive for 3 years and the battery has gone flat. I took it out of the car and opened the cell covers and the water/liquid level in all of them looks kinda low. Also a few of the cells look strange to me like there is a something white and cracked/broken inside of them. I have never looked inside a battery so don't know what to expect.

My question is, is there anything wrong with this battery, can I just add some distilled water and charge it?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

You can always try to see if it will work, there's absolutely nothing wrong with that, however, more than likely it's a dead soldier. Batteries have about a 5 year lifespan with proper maintenance (ie: regular recharging to keep them at peak charge). When a battery sits for three years without maintenance, they start sulfating and go bad. Once this happens, not much you can do with them but trade them in for a core credit. Again, you can always try, as it won't hurt anything.

I'd fill them up with distilled water like you stated and put it on a low amperage charger for a day or so and see what happens. It can't hurt to try.

In the future, if you're going to leave a battery/vehicle like that, either get a battery maintainer (not a trickle charger) to put on it, or at the very least disconnect it from the vehicle. While there is a small bit of power required for a vehicle which is shut off, it still continually draws power until it can't draw anymore. This is what really kills it in the long haul.